# Beginning java; compile time error

Tags: java

I am taking an intro to java class, and I have to make a chicken class with a method `walk()`. I have everything done, but the method `walk()`.

```
public void walk();
{
    System.out.print( Chicken + "is walking." );
}
```

This is what I'm trying, and I am getting a compile time error

```
Chicken.java:25: error: missing method body, or declare abstract

public void walk();


Chicken.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print( Chicken + "is walking." );

  symbol:   variable Chicken

location: class Chicken
```

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks!

Comment: There shouldn't be a `;` after the parentheses.

Comment: "missing method body" means it's expecting a `{` where your `;` is.  You might find using an IDE like IntelliJ makes it easier to find/fix these bugs.

Answer (score 2):

That is because of a semi colon after `walk()`. It denotes the end of statement, all you need to do is to remove it and the code will compile. E.g.

```
public void walk(){
    System.out.print( Chicken + "is walking." );
}
```